# How to modify the matched pattern

Tags: perl, sed

Just wondering if there is a handy way to modify matched pattern variable in Perl one liner. For instance in the string `abcdef` I'd like to replace `def` with `e` (output abce) using a command looking like this :

```
echo "abcdef" | perl -pne 's/(def)/{command that trims first and last character of $1 and returns it as a string for perl to use it as a replacement}/'
```

It would be easy to use such functionality to perform various formating tasks. Can we do this in sed ?

Comment: Why are you asking about sed if your whole problem description is about Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy in Perl with the `/e` flag:

```
echo 'abcdef' | perl -pe 's/(def)/substr $1, 1, -1/e'
```

`e` tells perl to parse the replacement part as a block of code, not a string. You can put arbitrary code in there.

But your concrete task (trimming the first and last character) can also be done like this:

```
echo 'abcdef' | perl -pe 's/d(e)f/$1/'
```

(Also, `perl -p` already implies `-n`. No need to specify both.)